# Nest JS Table is not creating. Written entities

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Team,

I have followed Nest.js and TypeORM documentations. Somehow tables are not generating in PostgreSQL. The database is connected successfully.

Nest Server running without error.
**Issue: The table is not generating.**

**src/tag/tag.entity.ts**

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
@Entity('tags')
export class Tag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

**src/app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from '@app/app.controller';
import { AppService } from '@app/app.service';
import { TagModule } from '@app/tag/tag.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Tag } from './tag/tag.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          envFilePath: '.local.env',
          // envFilePath: ".prod.env",
        }),
      ],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('HOST'),
        port: +configService.get('PORT'),
        username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DATABASE'),
        entities: [Tag],
        // entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: configService.get<boolean>('SYNC'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    TagModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**.local.env**

```
# DATABASE CREDETIALS
HOST=localhost
PORT=5432
USERNAME=mediumclone
PASSWORD=8170954991
DATABASE=postgres
SYNC=true
```

Please help me generate Postgres tables.
Framework - Nest JS
Database - PostgreSQL

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *username* is `mediumclone` but the database you're connecting to is `postgres`, so the tables are being created under the `postgres` table inside of the `postgres` server (I know, table and server being named the same is kinda confusing). Change the `DATABASE` env entry to be `mediumclone` and you'll get the result you want